# How to output folder hierarchy from Sharepoint

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, sharepoint, moss

I have a MOSS site where there is many folders and subfolders. I would like to output this folder hierarchy e.g. into a text file. How is that possible? Windows command line "tree" command does not work with UNC paths? Here is a desired example output from my local computer:

```
C:\temp\repos>tree
C:.
├───conf
├───db
│   ├───revprops
│   │   └───0
│   ├───revs
│   │   └───0
│   ├───transactions
│   └───txn-protorevs
├───hooks
└───locks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tree \\server\sitecollection\site` works fine for me (Windows XP)

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, DO NOT USE FOLDERS/SUBFOLDERS in a SharePoint doc lib. Yes, it works. No, it is NOT the preferred way to do things.
Metadata (custom columns) is by far a better way to manage your docs and what they are. Category/SubCategory = Folder/SubFolder. Makes finding/sorting/filtering your docs much easier and faster.
And you can trivially export that info out as a CSV/Excel/Text.

Try it.

Comment: I think the question is about the underlying folder structure of the install, not folders within libraries.

Answer (score -1):

You're better off doing this with an export to Excel, with a couple extra steps to show the folder structure. It's very easy. Check out my article on LinkedIn:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-export-sharepoint-document-library-excel-show-folder-cardonick

Comment: Answers must contain all information for the answer in the answer itself. It should not be necessary to follow a link to learn the answer, and promoting your own content in this way is just in bad taste.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks.

Comment: Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour]